# R EnhancedVolcano plot SelectLab - labels that would overlap don't appear

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, scatter-plot

thanks in advance for any assistance!

I am trying to label the top 10 up and down-regulated proteins in my data, but some of the labels don't appear. I think this is because some of the fold changes are very similar (eg 2.32 and 2.39).
Is there a way to fix this? My code is below:

```
if (!requireNamespace('BiocManager', quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages('BiocManager')

BiocManager::install('EnhancedVolcano')


library(EnhancedVolcano)

#to label select proteins, adjust list in "selectLab" below. Make sure to remove all spaces from rownames in CSV. I have provisionally adjusted for isoforms by adding a, b etc - correct for this!
#github.com/kevinblighe/EnhancedVolcano - good guide

EnhancedVolcano(mydata,
                lab=rownames(mydata),
                selectLab = c("HPX","DHX38","PPP1R7","PCDHGB4","RAD51D","LSM8","MYO9B","ACACB","ADAMTS13"),
                labSize=2,
                x="log2FoldChange",
                y="pvalue",
                title="Control v Treatment",
                legendPosition = "bottom",
                pCutoff = 0.05)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but as I had a similar issue recently, I decided to answer it anyways:

If the overap is the issue, EnhancedVolcano will throw you a very clear warning message like

Warning messages: 1: ggrepel: 6 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider increasing max.overlaps  2: ggrepel: 6 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider increasing max.overlaps

In this case your issue could be resolved by adjusting the max.overlaps like:

```
EnhancedVolcano(mydata,
                lab=rownames(mydata),
                selectLab=c("HPX","DHX38","PPP1R7","PCDHGB4","RAD51D","LSM8","MYO9B","ACACB","ADAMTS13"),
                labSize=2,
                x="log2FoldChange",
                y="pvalue",
                title="Control v Treatment",
                legendPosition = "bottom",
                pCutoff = 0.05,
                max.overlaps=Inf)
```

If you also used connectors, which is helpful when labeling very close data points, also increase maxoverlapsConnectors.
If there is no warning then your genes mights simply not be found in your table, which will throw you no warning. Therefore, double check your table. If you have a column with descriptions of genes, make sure to turn off the quotes when reading the table, as field like "5'-aminolevulinate synthase 1" will make a few lines disappear.

```
mydata<-read.table("mydata.myfilending",sep="mysep",header=TRUE,quote="\"")
```